# SVDF layer implementation compatible with TFLite's SVDF operator

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, svd

I need an implementation of an SVDF layer using Tensorflow 2.* that is compatible with TFLite's SVDF operator. That is, a layer that, after conversion to TFLite, generates an SVDF operator.

TFLite has a built-in SVDF operator (as listed [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/mlir/tfl_ops#tflsvdf_tflsvdfop)), but Tensorflow doesn't have an implementation for the SVDF layer.

I tried using the [implementation from Google Research](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/blob/master/kws_streaming/layers/svdf.py), but it doesn't generate the fused SVDF operation. In fact, when listing the operators from a model with this layer (using `tflite_model._get_ops_details()`), I get something like: `{'DEPTHWISE_CONV_2D', 'FULLY_CONNECTED', 'PAD', 'RESHAPE'}`.

The only example of a converted model that I could find with the SVDF operator listed was a .tflite file from Tensorflow's Github (avaiable [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro/blob/main/tensorflow/lite/micro/models/keyword_scrambled.tflite)), but there's no information on how this model was generated. When using `tflite_model._get_ops_details()` it gives out the following operators: `{'FULLY_CONNECTED', 'QUANTIZE', 'SOFTMAX', 'SVDF'}`.